# Regexp: match enumeration of predefined tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a term, let's say the `dog` and an example set of predefined tags: `red` and `big`. I'm trying to write a regexp that will match valid strings - those that have any combination of the tags where tag might be met zero or one time. Tags order does not matter.

Examples of strings that should match:

```
dog
red dog
red big dog
big red dog
```

Examples of strings that should not match:

```
red red dog
red big red dog
small red dog
```

The direct approach with just enumerating all possible combinations is a nightmare with dozens of terms.

This is where i've stopped for now:

```
/
    (?:                       # group for repetition
        (
            red\s | big\s     # a tag that ...
        )(?! \1 )             # ... is not followed by itself
                              # > (replacing backref with a recusional backref
                              # > still doesn't work, 
                              # > changing negative lookahead by a positive
                              # > still gives same undesired match on invalid strings)


    ){0,2}                    # such a term repeated 0 to [amount of terms] times
    dog                       # followed by a 'dog'
/xs
```

This regexp matches all the strings, which is undesired.

Comment: Is `big dog red` invalid?

Comment: Yes, it's invalid. `dog` is a string terminator that should always be found at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(?!.*\b(big|red)\h.*\b\1\b)(?:big\h+|red\h+)*dog$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vilYoD/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `^(?!.*\b(big|red)\h.*\b\1\b)`: Fail the match if any of the keywords appear more than once
- `(?:big\h+|red\h+)*`: Match 0 or more of `big` or `red` words followed by 1+ whitespace
- `dog`: Match `dog`
- `$`: End

Comment: It does the work just fine. Actually adding the line-start `^` in the beginning of the regexp in the question also solves this. Now i gotta figure out why =)